# how i can set all json code in Braces/{}?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

i have a question, how can i set a json code in Braces/{} ?

all code in down explained what i need do

i want to do this for login system if i have any error i'm sorry for that

look like that

```
{
  "test": "test",
  "test1": "test1"
}
```

that my code

```
var usac = JSON.stringify({username: newusername, password: newpassword }, null, 2)
fs.appendFile('account.json', usac, fin)

function fin(err){
console.log("done")
}
```

> that my json code

```
{
  "username": "test",
  "password": "test"
}{
  "username": "test1",
  "password": "test1"
}{
  "username": "test2",
  "password": "test2"
}{
  "username": "test3",
  "password": "test3"
}{
  "username": "test4",
  "password": "test"
}
```

> i want code be right that

```
{
  "user" :{
  "username": "test",
  "password": "test"
  }

  "user1" :{
  "username": "test1",
  "password": "test1"
  }

  "user2" :{
  "username": "test2",
  "password": "test2"
  }

  "user3" :{
  "username": "test3",
  "password": "test3"
  }
  
  "user4" :{
  "username": "test4",
  "password": "test4"
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems impossible to let one object has multiple same keys

Comment: Well don't use `appendFile` if you want to write a complete, valid JSON file

Answer (score 0):

You are appending to a `json` file. But, the content is not json.

One quick solution is:

1. Create the file with `{}` as initial content.
2. Read the file
3. Parse the contents to JavaScript Object
4. Set new account object in the parsed object with `username` as key & account object as value.
5. Stringify the JavaScript Object
6. Overwrite the same file with the stringified data

```
const fs = require('fs');
class AccountsInterface {
  constructor(filePath) {

    this.filePath = filePath;

  }
  
  getAll(callback) {

    fs.readFile(this.filePath, function onReadComplete(error, content) {
      if(error) {
        return callback(error);
      }
      const accountsMap = JSON.parse(content.toString());
      callback(null, accountsMap);
    });

  }

  addAccount(account, callback) {

    const self = this;
    self.getAll(function onAccountsLoaded(error, accountsMap) {
      if(error) { return callback(error); }
      accountsMap[account.username] = account;
      const accountsMapString = JSON.stringify(accountsMap);
      fs.writeFile(self.filePath, accountsMapString, function onWriteComplete(error) {
        if(error) { return callback(error); }
        callback();
      });
    });

  }

  // Async version
  async getAllAsync() {
    const content = await fs.promises.readFile(this.filePath);
    const accountsMap = JSON.parse(content.toString());
    return accountsMap;
  }

  async addAccountAsync(account) {
    const accountsMap = await this.getAllAsync();
    accountsMap[account.username] = account;
    const accountsMapString = JSON.stringify(accountsMap);
    await fs.promises.writeFile(this.filePath, accountsMapString);
  }
  
}

// Ensure this file's contents are `{}` in the beginning
const accountsFilePath = './accounts.json';
const accountsInterface = new AccountsInterface(accountsFilePath);

const account = { username: 'test', password: 'test'};
accountsInterface.addAccount(account, onAccountAdded);
function onAccountAdded(error) {
  if(error) { return console.log(error); }
  // here, the accounts file will look like {"test": {"username": "test", "password": "test"}}
}

// Async version
const account = { username: 'test2', password: 'test2'};
await accountsInterface.addAccountAsync(account);
// here, the accounts file will look like {"test": {"username": "test", "password": "test"}, "test2": {"username": "test2", "password": "test2"}}
```